# How can I align a certain tab to the right in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

Is it possible to have some tabs aligned to the right, but some tabs aligned to the left with bootstrap?
I want the tabs to be like:

Item - Item ------------------------------- Item

On opposite sides of the screen. Is it possible to do this?